# terminal window for git commands in android studio doesn't open

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have switched to system from laptop and setup git in android studio but I can't open terminal window to write git commands.
When I click on terminal, it just blinks the window and then disappears.

I'm attaching the screenshot. Terminal is boxed with blue color on clicking it, it just blinks the window and then closes it down.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL4ce.png)

While its giving me all the branches of git under this repo in this dialog:
then why is it not opening the terminal window and how should I initialize git and use it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6noFv.png)

Comment: Have you enabled it under `VCS`?

Comment: Please add the image to your question, not as a link.